# webpack-dev-server Tell dev server to reload the browser when any file matching a glob got updated?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a question. It seems the `webpack-dev-server` documentation only mentions [watchContentBase](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server) option which watches the content base directory. But is it possible to use `WDS` to also watch a glob pattern like `["./**/*.php"]` for file changes and reload the browser?

Currently I am using [`BrowserSync`](https://browsersync.io) to do this, but I feel this is redundant.

I found an internal method of [`WDS` `.watch( <pattern> )`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1073#issuecomment-328338808), but not sure how to insert this inside the `webpack.config.js`

Hope somebody can help.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [extra-watch-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/pigcan/extra-watch-webpack-plugin) that does exactly that

Answer (score 1):

First, thank you because your question was my answer - was trying to figure out where the server._watch method came from after seeing it in a tutorial project.

The way this method was used (successfully) in the tutorial was under the devServer.before method in webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    before: (app, server) => {
      server._watch('./app/**/*.html');
    },
  }
}
```